# Why were certain third-season episodes of seaQuest aired out of order?

Tags: continuity, seaquest

In the seaQuest 2032 season 3 episode "Spindrift":

> LT. James Brody is killed while attempting to rescue Lieutenant Henderson.

However, in "Brainlock", aired after Spindrift

> Brody is alive and an active character in the episode's plot.

According to [Wikipedia's List of seaQuest DSV Episodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_seaQuest_DSV_episodes), the episode numbers and air dates of "Sprindrift" and "Brainlock" are opposite. "Brainlock" was produced prior to "Sprindrift", thereby maintaining continuity of a very important event affecting the story, however they were aired in opposite order.

> "Spindrift" (#51): aired November 8, 1995
>
> "Brainlock" (#50): aired January 12, 1996

**Why did NBC air the episodes out of order?**

Comment: could it be a bug in Wikipedia?

Comment: No, they were definitely aired out of order by NBC. I distinctly remember the uproar it caused.

Comment: Usually its because of 'sweeps week' where they broadcast an episode perceived to be likely to gain higher ratings out of order.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any information to say for certain, but the simplest explanation is that there was some logistical issue that stopped "Brainlock" from being filmed/post-produced at the right time.  I come to this conclusion because on the wikipedia page you linked, its production number (which are generally given irrespective of air date) is also out of order.